# How to refer to the current value in XPath (XSLT)?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to run this XPath expression (that is, trying to count how many element content strings in my XML file end with letter-one-f ('a') or letter-two-f ('A'):

```
<xsl:value-of  select="count( substring(.,string-length(.) -1,string-length(.) -1)=$letter-one-f or substring(., string-length(.) -1,string-length(.) -1)=$letter-two-f )"/>
```

but I don't know how to refer to the 'current value'. All I know is that it's usually represented by a dot '.' . I don't know where to put 'template match' or if that is even needed.

This code, on the other hand, works, because I have specified that it should look in '/n-grams-sorted/n-gram':

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/n-grams-sorted/n-gram[starts-with(.,$letter-one-f) or starts-with(.,$letter-two-f) ])"/>
```

I just don't know how to apply this to the first expression. Where am I going to get 'the current value'? How am I going to tell it that I want to look in '/n-grams-sorted/n-gram'? It's all I need to get my expression working (I tried it in my editor's 'xpath view').

Source XML file sample:

```
    <n-grams-sorted analysis="N_GRAM_TOKEN3" range="Total Set">
        <n-gram position="1" frequency="3535" probability="0.0447735">. = =</n-gram>
        <n-gram position="2" frequency="322" probability="0.0040784">= = De</n-gram>
        <n-gram position="3" frequency="284" probability="0.0035971">= = Het</n-gram>
        <n-gram position="4" frequency="207" probability="0.0026218">= = Hij</n-gram>
        <n-gram position="5" frequency="168" probability="0.0021278">= = Dit</n-gram>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should show us the context of the first instruction, that is, you should show in which template the first `xsl:value-of` is placed.

Comment: I can't post the answer to that until 8 hours from now since I don't have 100 privilege yet. You can check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011714/using-xslt-how-do-i-increase-the-value-of-the-format-attribute-of-an-xslnumb  It contains the context for the first expression (just look at the expression in the value-of of the text param in the <xsl:call-template name="get-textblock">.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question anyway.

Comment: The linked question does not provide any information about the context in where the instruction is used. There are only two _named_ templates. What I'm asking you, is to show the matching template in which the instruction is used.

Comment: I am confused by what you are asking. Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/hCgWj5zf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
<xsl:value-of  select="count(/n-grams-sorted/n-gram[substring(.,string-length(.), string-length(.))=$letter-one-f or substring(.,string-length(.), string-length(.))=$letter-two-f ] )"/>
```

The whole problem was not the current node.. the problem was that I was getting '0' as a result all the time, because I was doing string-length(.) -1, which is incorrect, since that would mean "sonya" would become "sony" and start at 'y'. 'y' would never result in 'a', that's why 0... so the solution was to use string-length(.) .. without the -1.

Answer (score 0):

By the linked stylesheets it's clear you are not using template match at all. You are just matching the root node of the document (`/`) and then calling templates from that.

In this way your *current node* (`.`) is the document root. This can be verified by changing your XPath to:

```
n-grams-sorted/n-gram[starts-with(.,$letter-one-f) or starts-with(.,$letter-two-f) ]
```

or, the equal

```
./n-grams-sorted/n-gram[starts-with(.,$letter-one-f) or starts-with(.,$letter-two-f) ]
```

or, the equal

```
current()/n-grams-sorted/n-gram[starts-with(.,$letter-one-f) or starts-with(.,$letter-two-f) ]
```

Depending on what your are doing, if you are working on n-gram nodes only I think you can replace your stylesheet inital rule with:

```
    <xsl:template match="n-grams-sorted">
            <xsl:call-template name="draw-grid">
                    <xsl:with-param name="rcount">28</xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="ccount">6</xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="r">0</xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="c">0</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

and then simplify the XPath to:

```
  n-gram[starts-with(.,$letter-one-f) or starts-with(.,$letter-two-f)]
```

being the current node changed to the topmost one (**n-grams-sorted**).

Comment: I tried this approach and updated my code: http://pastebin.com/7pduGEMq but it gives me a runtime error as soon as I run it: "the value is not a node-set" at line 190 in the paste. I don't understand. I don't have problems with the starts-with[] lines, just line 190. It's that one that's not working.

Comment: The XPath expression you are using at line 190 is not the same I suggested.

Comment: I know it is not. What I need is an expression to find all n-gram nodes whose content ends with an 'a'. I try to accomplish this with: substring(.,string-length(.) -1, string-length(.) -1). This worked in xpath view, but only this way: substring(/n-grams-sorted/n-gram[@frequency='145'],1,1)='?'   I need a solution.

Comment: I do not know how or where to implement it. I need more clues.